# Routing traffic in nginx according to received header

Tags: nginx

I'm trying to route traffic in my nginx proxy according to a received header.

My infrastructure is built in a way that traffic is being sent to the proxy with a header that contains part of the address that I want to route to.

Here is my code:

```
upstream target {
    server $http_address.domain.com max_fails=3 fail_timeout=60;
}

server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    
    location / {
        proxy_pass http://target;
        proxy_redirect off;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
    }
}
```

Unfortunately I'm getting the following error when starting nginx:

```
host not found in upstream "$http_address.domain.com"
```

Is there any way I can dynamically edit the server's target url according to a given header?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An `upstream` `server` doesn't accept variables, but you can use it in `proxy_pass` directly. (And it doesn't really make that much sense to define an `upstream` with only one `server`.) For example:

```
    proxy_pass http://$http_address.example.com;
```

Comment: Still doesn't work... but for a different reason..
This time I'm getting:
```no resolver defined to resolve```

Comment: @NadavAviv OK, that's a different question.